# Nesting selectors - possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have a `div` with a bunch of stuff inside:

```
<div id="Product">
 <ul id="List"></ul>
 <div class="Component"></div>
 <input type=... />
 ...
</div>
```

Now, I want to style various things, but only when inside of the `#Product` `div`. Generally, I would do:

```css
#Product #List {}
#Product .Component {}
#Product input {}
```

But, can I do something like this instead?

```css
#Product {
    #List {}
    .Component {}
    input {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting CSS selectors is not possible with standard CSS, but there are other tools like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), and [XCSS](http://xcss.antpaw.org/) which allow you to write rules in the way you're describing.

These tools generally "compile" into real CSS which handles converting the nested selector syntax into real CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not in regular CSS.  You can use Sass!  http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't nest rules in CSS yet. There are CSS preprocessors available which allow cool features like nesting, variables, etc.

Check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).